Insert data through Excel to an existing SQL table using power query
I am working on a little PowerQuery project.

Insert data manually into an Excel table

When Enter or refresh this data get updated in the existing SQL table

Clear the Excel table for the next entry

Display a message in excel showing this get updated correctly

Following parameters used in SQL:
    @AccountNumber INT,  
    @PremiumPercentage DECIMAL(5, 2),
    @PremiumAmount DECIMAL(10, 2),
    @DateAdded DATETIME,
    @AddedBy NVARCHAR(50),
    @UserName NVARCHAR(50) - Windows name



Can someone help me to do this step by step please?

Show us what you have tried so far, and explain what is not working.
Also, this seems like homework. So you should probably try to solve it yourself.
